# How to create a menu banner to equal the total width of the browser?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I'm not too sure if I'm asking this correctly, but this is what I wanted to do: http://fedoraproject.org/

If you look at the provided link, you can see that the menu is all the way across the browser. Not only the menu, the footers and the banner below the menu too. I wanted to have a fixed layout for a website that I'm trying to build but have a menu to look exactly like that, how exactly should I go about it?

I'm using 960 Grids Framework so I'm not too sure if that'll messes it up :(

Thanks

Comment: as tyler said `width:100%;` and make sure any containers or wrappers it may reside inside of also has `width:100%`

Answer (score 1):

Each 'layer' will consist of a wrapping div **which is 100% wide by default** and an inner div set to your desired width...probably 960px in your case/

It might have the class `.container' but you can check your documentation for  that.

So something like this.

[**Codepen Dem**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oGKtA)o with colors for clarity.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner">HEADER HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="inner">MENU ELEMENTS HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="inner">FOOTER HERE</div>
</div>
```

**Basic CSS**

```
.inner {
  width:960px;
  /* or max-width:960px */
  margin:0 auto;
}
```